# Two select and a groupby in one statement spark.sql

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying this code:

```
spark.sql('''SELECT CD_CLI,
                CASE WHEN SUM(in_lim_crt) > 0 
                    THEN ROUND(SUM(SUM_VL_TTL_FAT)/SUM(in_lim_crt), 4)
                    ELSE -99999999999
                    END AS VL_MED_FAT,
                '2017-01-31' as DT_MVTC
         FROM in_lim_fat
         WHERE DT_MVTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
         UNION
         SELECT CD_CLI,
                 MAX(VL_RPTD_UTZO) AS MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO,
                 '2017-01-31' AS DT_MVTC
         FROM vl_rptd_utzo
         WHERE DT_EXTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
         GROUP BY CD_CLI
      ''').createOrReplaceTempView('media_vl_fatura_2017_01_31')
```

and I get the following error:

```
SparkStatementException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'in_lim_fat.`CD_CLI`' is 
not an aggregate function. Wrap '(CASE WHEN (sum(CAST(in_lim_fat.`in_lim_crt` AS BIGINT)) > 
CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) THEN round((CAST(sum(in_lim_fat.`SUM_VL_TTL_FAT`) AS DECIMAL(33,2)) / 
CAST(CAST(sum(CAST(in_lim_fat.`in_lim_crt` AS BIGINT)) AS DECIMAL(20,0)) AS DECIMAL(33,2))), 
4) ELSE CAST(-99999999999L AS DECIMAL(38,4)) END AS `VL_MED_FAT`)' in windowing func.....
```

The error message is huge so I just pasted the firts lines.

What am I doing wrong?
I want to create this table that is the union from the selected elements of the other two, but I  do not know much about spark.sql so is my query construction wrong? Does it not work this way?

Comment: Also add `GROUP BY CD_CLI` to the first query in your union (i.e. right above your union operator).

Comment: lol, simple as that!! thank you

Comment: just for a sanity check: how many columns must I end with? 3 or 4?